# detach() v remove.packages()

Tags: r

Is there a clear difference between use cases for detach() and remove.packages() in R? The help page for detach makes it sound like deleting a pointer, the package is still there but the environment doesn't know it, which seems problematic. Just solved a problem by using remove.packages() but new to R so wondering why detach seems more common.

Comment: `removes.packages` actually uninstalls the packages, i.e. the opposite of `install.packages`. `detach` just removes it from the search path, i.e. roughly the opposite of `library` or `require`.

Comment: @Axeman got it right, but I'd add:  you should rarely need either one.  It is generally harmless to have a package installed but not used, so `remove.packages()` is rarely needed.  You shouldn't need `detach()` if you only use `library()` or `require()` on well-behaved packages.  During development, restarting the session is generally a better strategy.

Comment: got it, background is that I'm using ggmap, the most up to date version of which needs to be installed from github with devtools and I think the presence of the CRAN version is creating problems so had to remove it. detach didn't do that.